# "<Order: Order object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to add multiple products or order items into a order and I'm using many to many relationship for that but when I try to create that order I get `"<Order: Order object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.` error, My code for adding and saving that order is like:

```
        userObject = UserLogin.objects.get(token=finalUserToken).user
        objects = OrderItem.objects.filter(user=userObject)
        FinalOrder = Order(user=userObject, order_id=another_token)
        for orderObject in objects:
            FinalOrder.products.add(orderObject.id)
        FinalOrder.save()
```

The error screen is pointing to this line

```
FinalOrder.products.add(orderObject.id)
```

I have also tried this

```
FinalOrder.products.add(orderObject)
```

but this gives the same result too

models.py

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
 

class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: Can you share the models? and what are you trying to do here `FinalOrder = Order(user=userObject, order_id=another_token)`

Comment: I edited my post and showed models.py

Comment: call `FinalOrder.save()` before the for loop starts

Comment: You need to `create()` or `.save()` the object before using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the **`save()`** method before the loop

```
userObject = UserLogin.objects.get(token=finalUserToken).user
objects = OrderItem.objects.filter(user=userObject)
FinalOrder = Order(user=userObject, order_id=another_token)

FinalOrder.save() # call the `save()` method here

for orderObject in objects:
    FinalOrder.products.add(orderObject.id)
```

Alternatively, you can commit the usage of `for loop` with ***list-unpacking***

```
userObject = UserLogin.objects.get(token=finalUserToken).user
objects = OrderItem.objects.filter(user=userObject)
FinalOrder = Order(user=userObject, order_id=another_token)

FinalOrder.save()
FinalOrder.products.add(*objects)
```